Strange result from Lagrange Inversion Theorem
In the document available here:
http://info.ifpan.edu.pl/firststep/aw-works/fsII/mul/mueller.pdf
I have been able so far to reproduce all missing details so far to the relation (33) of page 7:
$$\sin E=\frac{E-M}{e}=\sin M+\frac{e}{2} \sin 2 M+\frac{e^2}{8}(3 \sin 3 M-\sin M)+\ldots$$
However (it must be very likely obvious but i don't get it...) i don't understand how from (33) the author get (34), ie:
$$\sin 2 E=\sin 2 M+e \sin M 2 \cos 2 M+\ldots$$
Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

@ТymaGaidash I don't get it sorry. The double angle formula for sine has the same angles on the LHS and RHS. In my question the angles on the LHS never appear in the RHS. Thanks for your help
